# Laravel password hash is incorrect

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

i am trying to update password in Laravel, password is updating but when i try to login `it shows wrong details`,  i am not sure what i am doing wrong here.

```php
public function passwordupdate(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    // Column updating with incorrect Hash
    $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
    $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));
    $user->active = 0; // This value is updating correctly
    $user->save();

    return response()->json(['msg' => 'password updated']);
}
```

As I mentioned my request was posting a null value so I am adding Ajax code to figure why.

**Ajax**

```js
$('.update_password').on('click', function (e) {
    console.log('Update password clicked!')
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        url: "/users/" + $('#user_pwid').val(),
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.msg) {
                $('#response').empty();
                $(".toast").toast('show');
                $('#response').append(data.msg);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**View/Blade**

```php
<form method="post" id="policy-form">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" value="">
    <select name="name" id="user_pwid" class="form-control user_pwid border border-secondary border-dark" required>
        <option selected value="">SELECT USER</option>
        @foreach($users as $user)
            <option value="{{$user->id}}"> {{$user->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    <button type="click" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm update_password rounded text-center" value="{{$user->id}}"
            id="update-password"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203647/discussion-on-question-by-fayakon-laravel-password-hash-is-incorrect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

Controller Code:

```
public function passwordupdate(Request $request,$id) {
    $user = User::find($id);
    if(!is_null($user)){
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
        $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));
        $user->active =0;
        $user->save();   
        return response('success'); 
    }
    else{
        return response('failed'); 
    }
}
```

Ajax Code:

```
$('#update-password').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    },
    type: "post",
    url: "/users/" + $('#user_pwid').val(),
    data :{
        password : $('#password').val(),

    },
    success: function (data) {
        if(data == 'success'){
            alert('password changed successfully');
            $('#response').empty();
            $(".toast").toast('show');
            $('#response').append(data);
        }
        else{
            alert('failed');
        }
    },
    });
});
```

Try this it'll work

Comment: @Fayakon sure. let me know about and mark my answer as correct if it helped you :)

Comment: Thank you, it worked, can you please tell me what was issue with my code :)

Comment: @Fayakon Actually you were using serialize to send your password and you were accessing it directly as request in your controller.

Comment: Thanks, what if i want to add checkbox instead of password textfield, how to check if value is 1 or 0, for example i have checkbox, when it is checked controller should reset password to 123456.

Comment: this is to check your checkbox is slected or not   ::

 if($('#idofcheckbox').prop('checked') == true)

Comment: alwyas returns true in my case

Comment: That means it's always checked then

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain the problem with the original code, and what changes you made to fix it. This will make your answers more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Does `$request->password` actually have the intended password? Are you sure you haven't written a mutator on the model that is *double hashing* the password?

Is there a good reason you're creating your own password reset controller instead of using the one that Laravel ships with? Also - you *really* don't want to send the password back to the user in JSON.

Comment: i am testing right now, response would be different once i figure out what's wrong, i am trying to update guest password as admin, so i created another controller. i didn't change anything in model.